# How to lazy load images in jScrollPane?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jscrollpane

I would like to use jScrollPane as a thumbnail navigator for an image gallery, but some of the galleries have several hundered images, which oftentimes does not need to be loaded.

So i basically want to have the first few visible images loaded, and then if the user scrolls the pane to view other images in the current album, the images getting visible is loaded as they get near the viewport of the pane.

I have tried the lazyload plugin for jQuery, which does not seem to trigger inside a div with overflow auto.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the code for the plugin has been updated not so long ago. Here's the repository link:

https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

Hope it works this time else you can still have a go at those two alternatives:

http://ivorycity.com/blog/2011/04/19/jquery-lazy-loader-load-html-and-images-on-scroll

http://www.stylifyyourblog.com/2011/10/integrating-lazy-load-into-blogger.html